# Is it possible to have a crosshair in dojo candlestick charts? i.e. users get price and time of coordinate on mouseover?

Tags: dojox.charting

The desired functionality is that crosshair moves with mouseover and the horizonatal and vertical lines show price and corresponding timestamp.